# How to allow only two accounts per IP?

Tags: php, pdo, count

I'm trying to prevent multiple accounts from the same IP:

```
if (! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE ip = :ip");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row)
{
    die("Only one account per IP is allowed !");
}
```

This works, but what if I want to allow two accounts per IP ?  I tried:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip = :ip");
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row > 1)
{
    die("Only one account per IP is allowed !");
}
```

Doesn't work. The second account is not allowed.

Comment: This is a fundamentally misguided idea. What if 600 users are behind the same IP? It can happen. Also, note that the **only** reliable IP information you can use is `REMOTE_ADDR`. Everything else is fetched from client-side headers that can be **freely** spoofed.

Comment: @Pekka웃, is it possible ? What is then the purpose of IP ?

Comment: also PHP it's for scripting, if you want to impose this kind of limitations you are supposed to manipulate your http-daemon configuration, your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @Alegro the purpose of IP addresses is to provide an endpoint to send data to. That endpoint can be a router, though, it doesn't have to be an individual computer, and it often isn't

Comment: @Pekka웃, Mamma Mia ! Thanks a lot. Solved ! :)

Comment: @Alegro - users who connect to the internet via a proxy server would all seem to come from the same IP address (the public IP address of the proxy server).

Comment: if you can, try to use python, it's slow but is always better than PHP that looks and sound so 90's

Comment: @user1824407, python is better than php !? Give me some link, pls .

Comment: @Alegro use this framework and you will see https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be spoofed, and is trivial to do it. DO NOT USE IT. Use only REMOTE_ADDR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need count it.Using count()

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM users WHERE ip = :ip
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1):

Just update the query like below:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE ip = :ip");
```